# combining using statements and locks

Tags: c#, multithreading, using, locks

The following code is unsafe (or at least I assume it is):

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("path")) {
  MyTableCreationHelper.CreateTable(connection, "tableName"));
}
```

The problem is that if another thread tries to create a table on a different connection to the same path, the database will be locked, so an exception will be thrown.  To prevent that, I can do the following:

```
object lockObject = myLockHelper.GetUniqueObjectForLocking("path"); //does what it claims to do; implementation not shown
lock (lockObject) {
  using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("path")) {
    MyTableCreationHelper.CreateTable(connection, "tableName"));
  }
}
```

Now the code is safe, but also clunkier, as I have to wrap the using in the lock every time. My question is, is there a way to combine the using and the lock to make it less clunky?

Ideally, it would be done in a way that does not depend on the fact that our internal operation involves an SQLiteConnection. In other words, writing a locking wrapper for the SQLiteConnection is a less-than-ideal solution, because if the next time, my lock does not involve SQLite, the problem will recur.

Comment: Instead of putting the lock, I think you should be writing a try-catch inside the `using(var connection = new...){`. Try to create a table and if it throws the exception, you know the table is already there. Even better is to use something like `If(tableExists)` add rows to table, otherwise create it.

Comment: Are you sure the database will throw, for different "tableName"s ? Seems like something that would be easily serializable.

Comment: It did throw on me.  I'm not sure why -- it was caught at a generic level where that was no longer apparent.

Comment: It's not a question of the table existing.  The exception said "database is locked", which must mean another thread was accessing it.  Given what I was doing at the time, it makes sense that that would have happened.

Comment: Not sure if the locking just here is enough. CreateTable requires exclusive access, does querying / updating the Db from another thread at the same time work?

Comment: The crash would have been updating from another thread. But if all access locks on the path, it should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a generic wrapper class that takes an IDisposable parameter, and the same string parameter, which does the locking and upon which the using can be used

e.g.(untested code):

```
public class LockWrapper<T>:IDisposable
    where T:IDisposable
{
    T obj;
    object lockObject ;

    public LockWrapper(T obj, string Name)
         :this(()=>obj, Name)
    {
    }   


    public LockWrapper(Func<T> objcreator, string Name)
    {
        lockObject = myLockHelper.GetUniqueObjectForLocking("path");
        Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
        this.obj = objcreator();
    }

    public T Object{get{return obj;}}

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            obj.Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
        }
    }
}

//helper inside a static class

public static LockWrapper<T> StartLock(this T obj, string LockName)
    where T:IDisposable
{
    return new LockWrapper<T>(obj, LockName);
}
```

This was typed directly into SO, so don't even know if I've made syntax errors, but the idea remains the same, the wrapper object takes care of the locking.

A call would be something like:

```
using(var lck = new SQLiteConnection("path").StartLock("path"))
    MyTableCreationHelper.CreateTable(lck.Object, "tableName"));
```

Another way is to go lambda all the way and use something like

```
 public static void RunLocked<T>(Func<T> objCreator, Action<T> run, string LockName)
    where T:IDisposable
 {
    lock(getlockobject(LockName))
    {
        using(var obj = objCreator())
        {
            run(obj);
        }
    }
 }
```

But the call would be somewhat less intuitive:

```
    RunLocked(()=> new SQLiteConnection("path"),
            connection => MyTableCreationHelper.CreateTable(connection , "tableName"), 
             "path");
```